# How to make SVG map zoomable and scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

I am working on a website with a custom SVG map on the home page.

I already created a map with interactive points (usual link tags), which works pretty well. But the problem here is that map is big and needs to be larger then a screen size, especially on small devices.

I want map to be zoomable (without zooming all the page) and scrollable by dragging mouse (on desktop), also it needs to be centered by default.

I tried to use JqueryUI draggable method to achieve scrolling, and it works, but have some kind of conflict with the method I use to center it. And also absolutely stucks when I try to limit the draggable area.

Here is the latest example I have: https://codepen.io/khomutovspace/pen/jOVzbMe

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var outerContent = $(".map");
  var innerContent = $(".map > svg");

  outerContent.scrollTop((innerContent.height() - outerContent.height()) / 2);
});

$(function () {
  $(".map").draggable();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navigation {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.map {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div>
      <a>Title</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>Item 1</a>
      <a>Item 2</a>
      <a>Item 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="map">
  <svg>…
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another lib than jQuery UI, you can try [PanZoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom).

```js
  const mapElement = $(".map .svg")[0];
  const panzoom = Panzoom(mapElement, { contain: 'outside', startScale: 1.5 });
  
  mapElement.parentElement.addEventListener('wheel', panzoom.zoomWithWheel);
  mapElement.parentElement.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
    if (!event.shiftKey) return;
    panzoom.zoomWithWheel(event);
  })
```

For example : https://codepen.io/adrienlamotte/pen/bGgPgqj

Comment: Can't check all the functions it can offer, but I really like the fresh pen example you pinned. Thank you a lot for your advice!

Comment: I tried it out. Like the functionality. But have some issues. The problem is that it always tries to put map at the left or bottom and it's size make no sense. So maybe there is a way to center it? If it is ok, maybe I can somehow contact you?

Comment: The goal I am trying to achieve is a container with 100% (of the page) width and height. And a map itself right in the center with an ability to zoom and pan without changing the parent container characteristics.